# Call method on variable defined in :let clause in Rspec before all test cases?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I'm working on a chess program and trying to write tests for the Board class. The top of the spec file contained the following code:

```
describe Board do
    let(:board)       { Board.new }
    let(:empty_board) { Board.new(empty=true) }
    ...
end
```

However, I read that having boolean flags for methods is a code smell because it signifies that the method is responsible for more than one thing. So, I refactored the logic in the initialize method out into two methods in the board class: `create_default_board` which initializes the contents of the board to the default configuration, and `create_empty_board`.

In the spec file, however, I can't figure out how to call these methods on `board` and `empty_board`, respectively, before the individual tests are run without having to do so within each describe block. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Isn't it a case of `let(:board) { Board.create_default_board }` or similar? If not I don't follow your question, and might need more example code.

Answer (score 3):

#### Factory Methods

From your description this sounds like your specs are giving you feedback on the design. Based on your description:

> I refactored the logic in the initialize method out into two methods
>   in the board class: `create_default_board` which initializes the
>   contents of the board to the default configuration, and
>   `create_empty_board`.

To me that sounds like you are creating factory methods which would "let" you write:

```
let(:default_board) { Board.create_default_board }
let(:empty_board)   { Board.create_empty_board }
```

#### Using [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-tap)

The `tap` method yields the object to a block, then returns that same object from the block.

```
let(:default_board) { Board.new.tap { |b| b.create_default_board } }
let(:empty_board)   { Board.new.tap { |b| b.create_empty_board } }
```

#### Convert the Constructor Into a Builder

Some people dislike how the `tap` pattern looks. You can achieve the same pattern in a cleaner manner by yielding in your initializer:

```
class Board
  def initialize
    # ... your configuration ...
    yield self
  end
end
```

This allows you to write:

```
let(:default_board) { Board.new { |b| b.create_default_board } }
let(:empty_board)   { Board.new { |b| b.create_empty_board } }
```

#### Use Named Parameters in Ruby 2.x

An alternative to passing positional boolean flags is to pass named boolean flags. Since the parameter is named, it is clear what the caller is intending to do:

```
let(:default_board) { Board.new }
let(:empty_board)   { Board.new(empty: true) }
```

#### Inject the Configuration

Based solely on your description it is unclear what differentiates a "default" board from and "empty" board. Is it the dimensions of the board? Is this a 1-D, 2-D, 3-D, 4-D, or N-D board? Is it objects on the board? What are the default objects? Where are they located? Is it both of these?

By answering these, and likely other, questions you can flush out what parts of the board define the setup. For the sake of this example, and simplicity, let's say the board is one-dimensional and is defined by a size and a list of occupied indices:

```
class Board
  def initialize(size, occupied_locations)
  end
end
```

From this you could write:

```
let(:default_board) { Board.new(4, [0]) }
let(:empty_board)   { Board.new(4, []) }

# or perhaps an empty board has no size

let(:empty_board)   { Board.new(0, []) }
```

If there is a clear "default" you can provide default values for the parameters:

```
class Board
  def initialize(size = 4, occupied_locations = [1])
  end
end
```

Turning your `let`s into:

```
let(:default_board) { Board.new }
let(:empty_board)   { Board.new(4, []) }
```

#### Combining All the Above

Of course there's nothing stopping you, except maybe desiring to limit the API scope or adding a first class `BoardConfiguration` object, from writing:

```
class Board
  def self.create_default_board(&builder)
    new(size: 4, occupied_locations: [1], &builder)
  end

  def self.create_empty_board(&builder)
    new(size: 1, occupied_locations: [], &builder)
  end

  def initialize(size:, occupied_locations:)
    # ... your configuration ...
    yield self
  end
end
```

This essentially allows you to write any of the previous `let` statements.

Which of these methods is the best for your application, and specs, is really up to you. Everything is a balance of trade-offs.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `before` block outside the `describe` block of each individual method that you are testing.

```
describe Board do
  let(:board)       { Board.new }
  let(:empty_board) { Board.new } # empty=true

  before(:each) do
    board.create_default_board
    empty_board.create_empty_board
  end

  describe '#a_board_method' do
    subject(:a_board_method) { board.a_board_method }

    before do
      # Some other code here. It will be executed after the
      # first `before` block
    end

    # Finally the test, which is executed after all `before` blocks
    it { is_expected.to eq(42) }
  end
end
```

The first `before` block will be executed right `before` every assertion block you have. If you have more `before` blocks inside the `describe` blocks of individual methods, those blocks will be executed after the "main" before block.

You can check more about that [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks). There is a version for RSpec 3.2 [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks).

Regarding the class responsibilities, seems that your `Board` class could be two separated classes: `EmptyBoard` and `Board`. It would be easier to test them too. You could have that "initialization" code for each "strategy" right inside the `initializer` method of the specific class.